# Two external keyboards of the same type have different mappings

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use the Logitech K750 on my MBP at work and also bought the keyboard for myself to work at home with the same laptop (German PC layout!).
The problem is that **one** of the keyboards will always have the `^` and `<` keys swapped:

1. `sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` to reset the mapping
2. Plug in the K750 at work, select mapping: everything works fine
3. Come home, plug in K750, select mapping: `^` and `<` keys are swapped.
4. `sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` to reset the mapping
5. Plug in K750 again, select mapping: everything is fine
6. Come to work, plug in K750, select mapping: `^` and `<` keys are swapped.
7. Start from `1.`

The behavior is super annoying and I can't get my head wrapped around what is causing the issue because it's the exact same keyboard-type.
What is wrong with my keyboards?

Comment: What is the mapping (keyboard type) which you are selecting each time?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with what you are trying, but I've had success with [Karabiner](http://www.pqrs.org) for device-specific remaps, it's a little complicated to use but they have a manual on their site